# How to keep a line from being remembered in the history?

Tags: shell, command-history

This is for a single line, not a command. I found the way to make it always prevent history for a single command.

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for the poor wording.

Single line - For example, if I type, `git push production`, I might not want to accidentally execute this single line in the future, because it should only be run occasionally, and it has serious ramifications.

Command - In this example, the command is `git`. I would want the history to remember `git push; git push staging`

Single command - meant command as well.

Is this clearer now? Thanks.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "single line", "command", and "single command"?   The better you phrase your question, the more likely you will be to get a good answer.  as it is, this question is somewhat vague.

Comment: that's much better, thanks for clarifying.  i've run into problems a few times, where I just type `bash$ !rsync` or something, and end up running the wrong rsync account.  I can see how being able to keep the `git push production` command out of your history could be helpful.

Comment: I've been playing with the HISTIGNORE setting below, and that will do what you want.  `HISTIGNORE="git push production:&"` will tell bash to ignore the `git push production` command, as well as any duplicate commands (which cleans up history, especially if you run the same tail command or ls command repeatedly)

Comment: OK, thanks. What does `:&` do?

Comment: each ARG to HISTIGNORE is separated by `:`.  Much like $PATH.  The `&`, when supplied to HISTIGNORE, tells bash not to log history if the command you just ran is identical to the one before it.  It's a serial-deduplicator for shell history, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean when you contrast "command" and "line". I consider the command to be everything you type at the prompt until the shell interprets it - that's usually until you press <kbd>enter</kbd> unless it's inside a quote or escaped. In Bash, the `HISTIGNORE` environment variable lets you specify a list of patterns; if any of the patterns match the command, it will not record it in the history.

So if your `HISTIGNORE` contained `[ \t]*`, any command that started with space or tab would be ignored. That includes each of the following:

```
echo hi
echo hi; echo there
echo hi; echo there && echo fluffy
echo hi | cat
```